# Contradiction of Cauchy's Residue theorem?

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I have the following contour integral with the integrand

```
1/(2 Pi I)Gamma[-z]^(2)Gamma[1+z]^(2)
```

where the contour is an infinite semi circle running parallel to the imaginary line from -0.6-Infinity to -0.6+Infinity and semi-circular part in towards the positive real z-axis. On numerical integration using Mathematica, I obtain the result to be 1.0( code is given below)

```
NIntegrate[(1/(2Pi I))(Gamma[-z])^(2)(Gamma[1+z])^(2),{z,-0.6-20I,-0.6+20I}]
```

but when I apply Cauchy residue theorem I get zero because the residue for all poles at z=0,1,2,... and at z=-1,-2,-3... are all zero. Why is there a contradiction in the result?

This is my first question on Math StackExchange. Pardon me if my question is not well presented.

Comment: (1) The Mathematica code sems to square the Gamma function, but the integrand at the start of your question doesn't. (2) In your Mathematica code, what happened to the semicircular part of your contour?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The gamma functions in the integrand are indeed squared as in the Mathematica code.

Comment: The integrand will vanish on the semi-circular part so it is negligible even if the radius of the semi-circle is 10 units as I chose above to compute numerically.

Comment: I"m not at all convinced that the integrand will vanish on the semicircular part. $\Gamma(1+z)$ has very large values far out along the positive real axis, and $\Gamma(-z)$ has poles at positive integers, so getting the semicircular part of the integral to vanish will require some remarkable cancellations.

Comment: By the reflection formula $\Gamma(1+z) \Gamma(-z) = -\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ when $z$ is not a integer. So I think you should expect a non-zero contribution near the real axis.

Answer (score 2):

From the reflection formula

$$ \Gamma(1+z) \Gamma(-z) = - \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} $$

Its square is then equal to

$$ \pi^2 \csc^2(\pi z) $$

whose primitive we actually know to be $-\pi \cot(\pi z)$. So for any $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{a- \infty i }^{a + \infty i} \left[ \Gamma(1+z) \Gamma(-z)\right]^2 ~dz = \lim_{s \to \infty} -\frac1{2i} [\cot(\pi(a + is)) - \cot(\pi(a-is))] = 1$$

so the evaluation by Mathematica is not wrong.

---

The above result also indicates that the integral along the semi-circular arc is **not** negligible as you have assumed.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the value one using Cauchy's residue theorem?

Comment: @SumitBanik: what do you mean? By the residue theorem if you integrate around any closed contour you get zero for this integrand. You get +1 along the vertical line, and -1 along the circular arc.